# Spring paging parameters put to one DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parameters

I'm working on a Spring project, and the class shown below is one that some GET requests use as "paging parameters."

```
// PageDTO.java
public class PageDTO {
    int size = 10;
    int current = 0;
}

// RoomController.java - how I would use PageDTO
@GetMapping("get/rooms")
public List<Room> getUserRooms(
    PageDTO pageDTO, 
    @RequestParam(value = "user_id", required = true) Integer userId
) {
    List<Room> rooms = roomMapper.getByUserId(userId, pageDTO.getCurrent(), pageDTO.getSize());
    return rooms;
}
```

Problem is:

According to the regulations we use at work, PageDTO for GET requests is a bad design, but it did not explain why. The parameters should be changed to:

```
PageDTO pageDTO, 
@RequestParam(value = "user_id", required = true) Integer userId

// ->

@RequestParam(value = "current", defaultValue = "0", required = false) Integer current,
@RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "10", required = false) Integer size,
@RequestParam(value = "user_id", required = true) Integer userId
```

I see a lot of same code on Internet that use PageDTO or other similar classes. Can you clarify whether this design has any drawbacks? why it might be detrimental?

Comment: Why invent a paging parameters DTO when Spring Boot auto-configures support for [Pageable as a controller method argument](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.paging-and-sorting)?

Comment: the API should look the same. maybe they did the change for a different display in swagger-ui / openAPI?

Comment: @ChinHuang Good to know, but I think even if I changed to Pageable, it is still considered as violating the rules

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir Yeah, probably. If you got a minute, could you like share some information on the difference it will make to swagger ui when provided with / without PageDTO?